# Starting server - done! in IONIC 2 without run the project

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, web, ionic2

I an having some little problem's when trying to command my project to run with the 'ionic serve', command, inside of the application folder. Every time that i use this command the cmd return the message 'Starting server - done!' and don't run my program. 
I already tried to uninstall and reinstall my Cordova, npm and Node.js, at least five times, in each time using a different version of Node.js but without success. I tried to use gulp command in the last installation before the 'ionic serve' command, without success again.
This project of Ionic was downloaded in TFS, because my colleage create him im my enterprise and update to TFS, then i downloaded it.
Now my Node JS has the version 6.10.1 and my npm is in the version 3.10.10. I have a project to deliver in one week and are desperate to solve that.
I will be grateful for any help. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend, i solved in another way.

The person of my enterprise, who had uploaded the project don't put the node-modules folder. Than i copy the folder of him and put in my project, after i used 'ionic serve' command and everything just worked well.

Thank you for your help. I am very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the **node_modules** folder from your project.

Run the command `npm install` (It will recreate a fresh node_modules folder).

Then run `ionic serve`.